# In a TCP connection, what does "protocol copied data on bahalf of user" mean?

Tags: tcp, etw

I am using ETW (Event Tracing for Windows) to track certain network events such as:

- TCP connection accepted
- TCP data sent
- TCP data received, etc.

**If you are not familiar with ETW, that is OK, my question is about TCP protocol nuts and bolts**.
ETW basically broadcasts an event (eg, "TCP data sent") with relevant info (sender and destination addresses and ports, data size in bytes, etc), and my program consumes the events (for instance, I can add up the total number of bytes sent over a particular connection in its lifetime.)

My question is about an event provided by ETW named "KERNEL_NETWORK_TASK_TCPIP**Protocolcopieddataonbehalfofuser**". There is no documentation for this event, which is common when working with ETW. **Could anyone very familiar with TCP protocol give me a good guess about what this event signifies**? I am particularly curious if this event represents data being sent/received across the connection, or if it is "one sided" and doesn't involve transfer of data through the connection.

More info:

- The event contains sender and destination addresses and port numbers, as well as a "size" field, which indicates bytes transferred/received in other events, but might measure something else here.
- The event is always (based on my observations) followed immediately by a "Data Received" event, which has the same sender and destination addresses and ports, the same "size", and originated from the same process.
- However, "Protocol copied data on behalf of user" events appear to be somewhat uncommon, and "Data Received" events usually occur without that event preceding it.

Any ideas? That the event is followed by a data received event with similar parameters and size leads me to believe the event is probably not occurring "across the connection" but is measuring some operation on the receiving side(?). This is relevant to me because I need to know how to count the "size" of this event. If it is not a true transfer of data across the connection, I don't want to count it as such.
Thanks!

Comment: did you find it out what is one was for? I guess you did write a tool to check network latencies/retransmits or what is your goal?